# How to adding scroll bar and it work in Composite

Tags: java, swt, scrollbar, composite

```
ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        Composite composite = new Composite(sc, SWT.NONE);
        composite.setSize(1000, 1000);
        composite.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        composite.setBackground(parent.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
```

Display shown scroll bar but doesn't work

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should set content of ScrolledComposite, like this:

sc.setContent(composite);